# Core Plot: Are "setLabelingPolicy:CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone" and "setMajorGridLineStyle:majorGridLineStyle" Mutually exclusive?

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am trying to draw custom labels and Grid lines over Y-Axis,
If I set the Label Policy CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone, and add custom labels to Y-Axis, I could get the desired labels drawn on Y-Axis.

```
[yAxis setLabelingPolicy:CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone];
```

However I couldn't get Grid lines working.

```
[yAxis setMajorGridLineStyle:majorGridLineStyle];
```

If I remove Label Policy None, then I could get Grid lines.

Wondering what could be the solution?

Code for setting Y-Axis labels:

```
NSMutableArray *yLabels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"None", @"Awake", @"Light",@"Middle",@"Deep", nil];
NSMutableArray *customLabelsY = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[yLabels count]];
for (int loc=1; loc <= 4; loc++)
{
    CPTAxisLabel *newLabelY = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText: [yLabels objectAtIndex:loc] textStyle:textStyle];
    newLabelY.tickLocation = [[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:loc] decimalValue];
    newLabelY.offset = yAxis.labelOffset + yAxis.majorTickLength;
    [customLabelsY addObject:newLabelY];
}
[yAxis setAxisLabels:[NSSet setWithArray:customLabelsY]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone`, your app must provide tick locations (major and/or minor) if you want tick marks and/or grid lines. They are independent of the labels, so you can label locations that don't have tick marks and/or skip some of the tick locations when creating labels.

---

Edit:

Keep track of the locations when creating your labels and set the `majorTickLocations` when done.

```
NSMutableSet *locations = [NSMutableSet set];

for (int loc=1; loc <= 4; loc++) {
    // create labels

    [locations addObject:@(loc)];
}

yAxis.majorTickLocations = locations;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for the late response. I have posted How am I setting the labels. Please check my code. The problem still exists as explained in the original question.